# Issue installing devtools on R and dependency on usethis and fs

Tags: r

I am trying to get the `devtools` to work on RStudio. I installed the package using:

```
install.packages("devtools")
```

when I run

```
 library(devtools)
```

I get the error:

```
Loading required package: usethis
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘usethis’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘fs’
Error: package ‘usethis’ could not be loaded
```

so I try to install `fs` using `install.packages('fs')` yet when I run `library(fs)` I get error of `Error in library(fs) : there is no package called ‘fs’` furthermore I installed `usethis`yet I guess that depends on `fs` because when I run it I get:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘usethis’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘fs’
```

I wonder how to resolve this?

Comment: We need more info.  What operating system? What R version?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I added it to the comments on the Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the Rcpp package dependency. Install it with:

```
install.packages("Rcpp", dependencies = TRUE)
```

Comment: And [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/cannot-install-devtools-for-r-version-3-6-1/41362/4) is a source for this suggestion. Read last 5 comments

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Package `fs` no longer use Rcpp:  https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/fs/index.html

Comment: Consider also restarting your R session to clear any background process that may be preventing the install

Comment: So the issue resolved by first running `install.packages("Rcpp", dependencies = TRUE)` and then running `install.packages("fs")` from binary. I use MacOS and my R version is 3.6.3 running on the RStudio.